# Can't open disassembly window on VS15

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I've tried all solution out there and still can't find that window in Visual Studio 2015 , even under the command window throwing this Error :

```
Command "Debug.Disassembly" is not available.
```

Is there any solution to find that window under VS15 ?

Comment: Is your app complied in debug?

Comment: Odd, I ran a random app, at a break point, I hit ctrl+alt+d and my window appeared.. and was working.

Comment: thx I was not using the break point now it works , rewrite your comment in an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: glad to find you an answer - done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While its not a window I've used much, I ran an app from vs, which had a breakpoint. On reaching the break point, the window can then be opened.